# Reset your PATH variable

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, path

I stuffed up (basically wiped) my PATH variable.

Is there any way to reset it to the default?

I look at [How do I reset the $PATH variable on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/121870/how-do-i-reset-the-path-variable-on-mac-os-x), but I find it very confusing.  As far as I know I stuffed up my `~/.profile` file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have the following in my `~/.profile`:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

The first `PATH` declaration overrides any existing `PATH` setting (it doesn't include `$PATH`). The path used is the OS X default.

The second line appends `~/bin` to the `PATH` and it is a personal preference, not a default.

After edit, restart your session — or use command `source ~/.profile` to activate the changes immediately.

Comment: Thanks a million man - everything so far has been insanely confusing - your advice is incredibly straightforward and easy to follow

Comment: Better to use ~/.bash_profile for this simple case and in more general ~/.bashrc and source that in your ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

The file can have the name `.bash_profile` or `.profile` - one solution could be to rename the file e.g. `mv ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_prolile.old` and then restart your machine and see if it helped.

You can also try to edit the file, and then maybe you'll see the wrong PATH, which you then can edit.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of logging in as a normal user and invoking `su - root`, I found that Mac OS X 10.8.5's bash was ignoring `.profile` and `.bash_profile`; I was unable to change root's `$PATH` by editing those files.  What *did* work was editing `/etc/paths`. After exiting the root shell and entering again with `su - root`, the new path was present.

Comment: Messing with system paths could generate instability.

Answer (score -1):

Resetting your terminal will work. It will reset your basic configurations.

***Reset your terminal***. From top navigation go to **Shell >> Reset.**

[image]