# How can I add a path to the PATH environment variable?

Tags: terminal, path

I want to add a path to the `PATH` environment variable?

I have tried with `export PATH=/mypath:$PATH` and it works. But the next time I start the Terminal, my new path is not int the `PATH` environment variable any more.

How can I add a path to the `PATH`environment variable? and it should be there also the next time I start the Terminal.

---

I have problems with this now again, the trick that worked before doesn't seem to work anymore.

I have tried with:

```
echo 'export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/jonas/gradle-1.2/' >> ~/.profile
echo 'export PATH=GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
```

to add two environment variables. Then my `~/.profile`-file has this content:

```
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/jonas/gradle-1.2/
export PATH=GRADLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

But when I start a new **Terminal** window and type `gradle` (the command I added to `PATH`), I get a message that the command doesn't exists. If I run the command from `/Users/jonas/gradle-1.2/bin` it works fine!

Comment: If you happen to screw something up, see also: [Reset your PATH variable](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/11745/1453)

Comment: The assignment to PATH (second export) should be with $GRADLE_HOME

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`echo 'export PATH=/my/path:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile` should do the trick!

If you used `echo 'export PATH=/my/path:$PATH' > ~/.bash_profile`, or any such variation, you would be overwriting the contents of your profile!

Comment: **Note**: If it isn't obvious, `.bash_profile`is a text file and you can also directly open and edit it to add any path either with the command `nano ~/.bash_profile` in the Terminal or using TextEdit ( https://superuser.com/a/912645 ).

Answer (score 13):

OSX reads the following files in order when a terminal opens :

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login   
~/.profile
```

So place your path addition into one of these.  I normally put additions into `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks, I used `echo 'export PATH=/mypath:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`

Comment: Is this still correct now that the default is zsh on Macs?

Answer (score 5):

### Updated at 2021.0908

I'm using this:

```
~/.zsh/
├── .fzf.zsh
├── .zcompdump
├── .zprofile              # This will be read before .zshrc.
├── .zsh_functions         # This is for my custom scripts.
├── .zsh_history
├── .zshenv                # (Important) Create a symlink of this to your ~/.
└── .zshrc                 # Put everything in this file is fine. (cont.)
                           # (cont.) this is the ".bashrc" in your head.
```

Some points:

- My `.zprofile` is empty. I prefer to put all stuff inside `.zshrc` because it doesn't contain too many lines.
- The content of `.zshenv` **SHOULD** contains this line so that we can organize the .zsh family into the `~/.zsh` folder, **AND** don't forget to symlink it into your `~` folder where your OS can read:

```
ZDOTDIR=/.zsh
```

**DONE**. You can ignore my old answer follows.

---

### Old answer: (Not correct. Put everything inside `.zshrc` is just fine.)

Old question but, for MacOS X Catalina users:

<strike>Create/edit `~/.zshenv`:</strike>

```
# comment for yourself
PATH="$PATH:to/your/path"
```

Notice that modify `PATH` in `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc` is not correct, it should be `~/.zshenv`.

If you need to prepend something to `PATH`, further create/edit `~/.zprofile`:

```
# apply the prepend to PATH
[[ -r ~/.zshenv ]] && source ~/.zshenv
# remove duplicate in PATH
typeset -U PATH
```

Reference: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: What do you mean with "If you need to prepend to the PATH" and why can't this be done in `.zshenv` as well?

Comment: In short it's a matter of loading order. `path_helper` will be executed after `~/.zshenv` but before `~/.zproflie`. And from my study today I would recommend using symlink instead of modify `PATH`, which is much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the places mentioned by  @RobZolkos, the login shell also looks in `/etc/paths` and the files inside `/etc/paths.d/`. One path entry per line in these files.

See `/etc/profile` and the [manual page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html) for `path_helper`.

Comment: Ok, thanks! but the biggest problem was how to add the path. But I found `echo 'export PATH=/mypath:$PATH' >> ~/.profile`

Comment: @Jonas: I realized that your problem was solved. My answer was intended for the benefit of future readers, so they can see all the options available to them.

Answer (score 0):

Insert in .bashrc these lines of code:

```
function pathadd {              # Add new element to PATH
  if ! echo $PATH | egrep -q "(:|^)$1(:|$)"
  then if [ "$2" = "after" ]
       then PATH="$PATH:$1"
       else PATH="$1:$PATH"
       fi
  fi
}
```

then type a command like: `pathadd /opt/local/bin` or `pathadd /opt/local/bin after`.

Comment: Note the two functions in fink’s init- https://github.com/fink/base-files/blob/master/init.sh.in