# How is $PATH created?

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, path, php

I am still relatively new to the workings of the Mac OS but have extensive knowledge of Linux.  I updated my php on Mavericks using the php_osx and the instructions stated to use `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` to have the new php version used.

Through my attempt to update php I found references to the following files:

- `.bash_profile` - I can not find this file.
- `.bashrc`
- paths
- path_helper

Can someone please provide a simple understanding of how $PATH is created in Mavericks and help me understand where the export command put the edition to the path and how would I remove it if I want too?

Comment: Do the answers to this question help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/how-can-i-add-a-path-to-the-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OS X you'll have following :

The base PATH used is located in `/etc/paths`. It is used to set `$PATH`.

By default, the file contains :

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

It will also load the paths located in `/etc/path.d/`.

When opening the terminal I will load :

1. `~/.bash_profile`
2. `~/.bash_login`, (if .bash_profile doesn't exist)
3. `~/.profile` (if .bash_login doesn't exist).

These files can load some other files, for example `.bashrc`.

If you want to expand your path you can do it in one of the files by adding your  `export` command you gave in your question.

Comment: Right! I updated that part.

Comment: Matthieu thanks for the response.  However I have never created a .bash_profile or .bash_login or .profile and can not find them.  There is a /etc/bashrc file and the only file in the path.d directory is 40-XQuartz. The /etc/profile file seems to point to path_helper.  I can not seem to find where the export command I ran went to and how I would remove it if I wanted too.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `export` has only a effect on the current bash session.

Comment: Ok. Getting closer to an understanding.  What does the export in my example do then that allows the php to always use the new version that is in a different directory then the preloaded version.

Comment: If you want to have your path changed in every session, you have to put it in a file loaded with every new bash session. For example in one of the 3 files given above. If you haven't one, you can create it.