# Why do I get this message every time I open the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Every time I open the terminal I see the following message:

```
/etc/zshrc:7: command not found: locale
```

This is the first 7 lines in the file /etc/zshrc:

```
# System-wide profile for interactive zsh(1) shells.

# Setup user specific overrides for this in ~/.zshrc. See zshbuiltins(1)
# and zshoptions(1) for more details.

# Correctly display UTF-8 with combining characters.
if [[ "$(locale LC_CTYPE)" == "UTF-8" ]]; then
    setopt COMBINING_CHARS
fi
```

What should I do to this file to fix the problem?

Comment: Is the binary `/usr/bin/locale` present on your system ? If so, modify PATH or equivalent so that it can be found. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275343/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-path-when-using-zsh-in-sierra

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/paths`?

Comment: Also, what's in your `~/.zprofile` and `~/.zshenv` (if they exist), and what does `printf '%s\n' $path` print? (Edit these into the question, using code format so they're readable.)

Answer (score 1):

Your zsh environment isn't finding locale in its PATH.

Either call locale by its full path:

```
if [[ "$(/usr/bin/locale LC_CTYPE)" == "UTF-8" ]]; then
```

..or update your $PATH to make sure that /usr/bin is included.

Comment: yes that describes the issue - but is not the OPs problem. The problem is  why is /usr/bin not on their path

Comment: if [[ "$(/usr/bin/locale LC_CTYPE)" == "UTF-8" ]]; then    -                       It doesn't work, the result is  "then>"

Comment: I tried to edit the file but it's locked (permission denied)...

Comment: how can I edit it?