# If the new MBPs (M1) come with Python3 pre-installed, why don’t Python scripts run in shell?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, python, apple-silicon

I've been reading through lots of "how to"s on using Homebrew to install Python3 and Python packages, but from my terminal queries, it looks to me that Python3 is already installed:

```
MBP21:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
MBP21:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
MBP21:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
MBP21:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
MBP21:~$ where python
/usr/bin/python
```

But when I started `venv`, installed Django (successfully), and did `manage.py runserver`, I got this message:

```
WARNING: The script sqlformat is installed in '/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script django-admin is installed in '/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed asgiref-3.4.1 backports.zoneinfo-0.2.1 django-4.0 sqlparse-0.4.2
```

And when I tried to use `manage.py runserver`, I got this error message:

```
    zsh: command not found: manage.py
```

I may be conflating different issues here, but am not sure where to start fixing the problem. Appreciate some tips.

Comment: Did you add the directory to PATH as mentioned in the messages you got?

Comment: How exactly are you using venv and how did you install the scripts

Comment: @mmmmmm I didn't (intentionally) install any scripts. I tried to start working on some Django projects that I copied over from a previous laptop. All the Django apps use venv (`python3 -m venv ./venv`), which I learned from a tutorial.

Comment: Start with the python docs for venv https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html You have set up the environment but you are not using it. You need to activate it

Comment: @mmmmmm I did activate `venv` (n VS Code), that's when I got the error message: 
`WARNING: The script sqlformat is installed in '/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script django-admin is installed in '/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.`

Comment: How EXACTLY did you do these things so we can reproduce. Nothing you have shown would try to put anything in Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin - unless you did it directly from python3 without activating a venv

Comment: @mmmmmm Ah-maybe this is where things went wrong: I activated `venv` at the beginning, but instead of `pip3 install django`, I did `pip3 install python`--got a bunch of error messages and I realized it was Django I wanted to install. So perhaps Python3 got installed instead. 1) Can I just go ahead and delete `'/Users/ysl/Library/Python/'? 2) Python3 is installed at `/usr/bin/python`--that's the system installation, right? Shall I go ahead, install Homebrew to install Python3?

Comment: If you use venv USE venv  Activating will change your paths for pip and python3 so that where will point to the correct venv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you that it installed binaries/scripts at a non-standard location that's not included in your `PATH`. This means they won't be found when you simply enter their names like `manage.py` without their full path.

You need to add `/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin` to [your zsh `PATH`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/425894/9849) (and then restart your shell/terminal).

Comment: The link eventually leads to an article in dev.to, which I've read--but which circles me back to a fundamental confusion on my part (pardon the ignorance): By adding (exporting?) PATH, will the installation of Python in `/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin` be accessible to other Django apps? If not, do I need to install a version of Django (maybe using Homebrew) to make Python work with all other Django apps? I'm hoping to keep the system clean and not have too many different installations as I did to the previous laptop.

Comment: This is sort of correct in that you need to add things to the path but if you are using venv then that is the wrong thing to add.

Comment: Just realized (duh!) that VS Code complained the script not on the path of `'/Users/ysl/Library/Python/3.8/bin'`--which is a different path from  `/usr/bin/python3` where the Python 3.8 executable is located. What concept/keyword can I use to figure out the distinction btw the two?

Comment: The concept is venv - please read the manuals. venv alters your environment so each environment has a different path  and version of python and libraries.

Comment: @mmmmmm I get that. Tried multiple times to read the docs but, due to gaps in my knowledge, the docs left me more confused. Thanks-I'll try again.

Comment: Basically run activate in your shell before running python or pip - I don't know how VSCode switches venvs But PyCharm asks you for the path to the venv for the project