# Right way to add paths to PATH in mojave

Tags: terminal, mojave

I'm not clear how to add permanently paths to the PATH env var. I've found several questions for this each time with a different answers.
I created a `.bash_profile` in my home dir, but each time I reboot I have to manualy `export` my paths again.

`source ~/.bash_profile` doesn't even work.

What am I missing?

This is currently my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "source ~/.bash_profile doesn't even work"? Do you get an error mesage?

Comment: Quit Terminal, then reopen it... what's the result of: `echo $PATH`

Comment: @user3439894 yeah that's strange, actually the paths are all here, first row excluded (the python one)

Comment: I was expecting you to post the the result of `echo $PATH` so I could see explicitly and specifically what the result was. Sorry, but I can't help if I'm not given the info I request!

Comment: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Okay, I added `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"` to the top of my `~/.bash_profile` file and it sourced it properly when reopening Terminal. I'd suggest swapping the first two `export PATH=` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I swapped the lines and it looks I solved.. not sure why. Thanks!

Comment: Without having first looked at the `~/.bash_profile` file in a hex editor before it was edited per my suggestion I can't say for sure, but sometimes toggling the bit, so to speak, will fix an error.

Comment: yeah some invisible char would be the only reason. Thanks

Comment: **See Also**: [How can I add a path to the PATH environment variable?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12629/74706)

Comment: I had to add PATH info to `~/.zshrc` as my Mac used `zsh` as default shell.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What you've laid out is the proper way to add additional directories to your user's `$PATH`.

(*NOTE: These instructions are for Macs that use the `bash` shell. As of macOS 10.15 (Catalina), Macs use `zsh` by default. All the steps below still apply with the exception that the file is `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`. If you're unsure which shell you're using you should be able to run the command `ps -p $$` to figure it out*)

#### Step 1 - `~/.bash_profile`

To start make edits to your `~/.bash_profile` adding whatever locations you'd like to have amended to your `$PATH`.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
```

#### Step 2 - source `~/.bash_profile`

After making the above edits to this file you can either use the `source` command or the `.` notation to "reload" and changes made to this file in your current shell's context.

```
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

-or-

```
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

#### Step 3 - Evaluate changes

After making the edits and sourcing them you can confirm they had the effect you desired by echoing the contents of the `$PATH` varible.

```
$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
/usr/local/sbin
/Users/smingolelli/bin
/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
/Users/smingolelli/projects/kubebuilder/kubebuilder_1.0.5_darwin_amd64/bin/
```

The order matters, so directories that occur first will be searched first. If a binary lives in multiple places, the first place encountered will be the one that is used.

Also keep in mind that multiple sourcings of this file will have a negative effect of continuing to add the same changes, so it's often the case that you'll want to completely se the `$PATH` to a consistent known initial state and then amend it with these types of commands:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin"
export PATH="/some/new/dir:$PATH"
```

#### Using path_helper

macOS also includes a helper to assistance in the management of your `$PATH`. It's located here `/usr/libexec/path_helper`.

So instead of manually crafting your base `$PATH` as mentioned above you can instead use this snippet to get a known good starting point for your `$PATH`.

```
[ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ] && eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

This will take care to initialize `$PATH` so any directories listed in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` get added automatically.

Comment: It might be better to use `[ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ] && eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)` to initialize the path so any directories listed in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` get added automatically.

Comment: @nohillside makes sense. I wasn't aware that macOS had this helper, thanks, I'll add to A'er.

Comment: Have a look at `/etc/profile`. It's not much going on there, but initialising `PATH` is part of it.

Comment: Just a head's up, my `~./bash_profile` just routes to `~/.bashrc` which is the actual file I had to modify.

Comment: @slm `[ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ] && eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)` removing the second part gives me the same result as just using the first part when I `source ~/.bash_profile` more than once. Maybe an explanation of what each part does would be helpful.

Comment: @slm The advice under "Using path_helper" causes me to have duplicates of any paths I have exported in ~/.bash_profile. If we are adding paths on a per user basis inside ~/.bash_profile how do we avoid duplicating them with this solution?

Comment: A note when adding a path via export it makes a difference where you put "$PATH". `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/nano/bin:"$PATH"` prefixes to path instead of appending and `export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/opt/nano/bin` appends to path instead of prefixing.

Comment: This does not seem to "permanently" add the paths to PATH. I need to source this .bash_profile every time I reopen the terminal. Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed that the macOS shell is now ZSH. How do I do this for ZSH?

Comment: @AaronFranke - instead of adding the lines in step one to `~/.bash_profile`, you add them to `~/.zshrc`