# Command "istats" gives "-bash: istats: command not found" after "gem install iStats"

Tags: terminal, command-line, install, macos

I wanted to use iStats in command line/terminal mode, so I did the following:

- I installed iStats with the command `gem install iStats` as per [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/can-i-get-the-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/127453#127453) to an AskDifferent question;
- However, when I issue the command `istats` I get a `-bash: istats: command not found`;
- Issuing the command `gem list` shows me that iStats is installed (`*** LOCAL GEMS ***` and in second position it reads `iStats (1.6.1)`;
- I checked and the app resides in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/`;
- Issuing a `gem environment` command shows the following `- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0`;
- I uninstalled the Gem by issuing `gem uninstall iStats`;
- Then issuing `gem list` shows that the app was indeed removed;
- Then I issued `gem install iStats` that gave the following output:

  `Fetching iStats-1.6.1.gem
  Building native extensions. This could take a while...
  Successfully installed iStats-1.6.1
  Parsing documentation for iStats-1.6.1
  Installing ri documentation for iStats-1.6.1
  Done installing documentation for iStats after 0 seconds
  1 gem installed`
- Issuing `istats` command gives again `-bash: istats: command not found`.

Any ideas?

---

System used (just in case):

- macOS Mojave Version 10.14.5
- Ruby version: ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- Processor: 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory: 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 1536 MB

Comment: Well, is the program in your path?  echo $PATH

Comment: @historystamp; thanks for the comment. Indeed I haven't done that. Problem solved. Thank you. Will post the solution…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to historystamp's comment here is how the problem was solved (for bash shell):

1. Open/Launch Terminal
2. `gem uninstall iStats` ([source](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-uninstall-a-ruby-gem))
3. `gem install iStats --user-install` ([source](https://bundler.io/doc/troubleshooting.html))
4. `export PATH="~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH"` ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358687/right-way-to-add-paths-to-path-in-mojave))
5. `source ~/.bash_profile` ([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358687/right-way-to-add-paths-to-path-in-mojave))
6. `istats`

If you use macOS Catalina, the default shell is zsh. The adapted instructions are the following:

1. Open/Launch Terminal
2. `gem uninstall iStats` ([source](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-uninstall-a-ruby-gem))
3. `gem install iStats --user-install` ([source](https://bundler.io/doc/troubleshooting.html))
4. Open or create `~/.zshrc`
5. At the end of the file (or where appropriate) insert: `export PATH=~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:$PATH` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530090/adding-a-new-entry-to-the-path-variable-in-zsh))
6. Save file `~/.zshrc`
7. Source the .zshrc file: `. ~/.zshrc` ([source](https://medium.com/@grantbrits/editing-path-variable-in-catalina-mac-osx-5532ba447af9))
8. `istats`

Comment: Are you meant to be have to be super user to install iStats? I get an error `No rule to make target `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/...` when I try to install  like this

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no need to be in 'su' mode in order to do the installation (otherwise I would have written it). Nevertheless, have you tried using it?

Comment: I found that the best way to install it is likely to `brew install rbenv`, then `rbenv init`, then `rbenv install -l`, `rbenv install 3.2.2`, `rbenv global 3.2.2`, then finally `gem install iStats`