# Homebrew "`split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)"

Tags: terminal, homebrew, error, ruby, macos

I tried to install `asitop` through `brew` but it doesn't exist (yet) as a package (see comments).

The tentative installation triggered an update of the existing `brew` packages. From then on, each time I invoke a `brew` command I get the following (even when issuing a `brew doctor` command):

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `block in parse'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:93:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:124:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:124:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

`echo $PATH` renders the following:

```
?/usr/libexec:/Users/profilename/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/Users/profilename/Library/Python/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

I stumbled on this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482265/homebrew-and-ruby-error-with-utf-8-and-split), but unfortunately I failed to generalise the solution to my case.

Kindly note that I have `istats` installed (see [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/363518/70284) for installation procedure).

Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: There's no such package `asitop` in the main Homebrew repo. Have you installed it from a 3rd party repo? You'll also have to elaborate on why the installation of `istats` is relevant.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths: Thanks for your comment. Just checked and you're correct. I guess that what I thought being the installation of ```asitop```, was the ```Running `brew update --auto-update`...```. Also I specified that ```istats``` is installed because it's intallation affected the result of the ```echo $PATH``` command (I thought it might be relevant at some point).

Comment: Please **edit** your question to focus on the actual problem, details in comments easily get lost.

Comment: Also, what is the `?` doing at the beginning of `PATH`?

Comment: @nohillside. Thanks for your comments. I have no idea why there is a ```?``` at the beginning of the result of ```echo $PATH```. I only pasted the result of the command. Should I remove it? If yes, how?

Comment: type `export PATH=`, copy/paste the good part of the path (make sure there is no space after the =, then press enter. Then rerun the brew command again. This will not solve the ? issue in general (we come to that later) but helps to figure out what is breaking brew.

Comment: @nohillside. Thanks for your answer. That seem to have done it! As suggested I exported the PATH with the content in the question, but without the leading ```?```and ```brew doctor``` does not throw the mentioned error back (I just have some warnings that homebrew says I can ignore if everything works for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I used `Homebrew` for about 3 weeks several years ago - a dismal, frustrating experience. Then I learned about [`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org/) - been using it ever since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `?` at the beginning of your PATH which for sure should not be there. If it persists (open a new Terminal tab to verify), you need to look through the startup files of your shell and into `/etc/paths`/`/etc/paths.d/*` to check where it gets added.