# Adding to PATH doesn't add to autocomplete

Tags: terminal, bash, path

I have a Go binary (called [AssetFinder](https://github.com/tomnomnom/assetfinder)) that I want to add to my `$PATH` so that I can autocomplete it. The binary is at the location `/Users/spike/go/bin` and I can execute it by `cd`ing to that directory and running `./assetfinder` but I don't want to `cd` to this directory every time I want to use this tool. So I tried to addd the path of this tool to my `$PATH` variable as well as update the `~/.bash_profile` too.

I found a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358687/right-way-to-add-paths-to-path-in-mojave) and I tried to see if the `$PATH` variable is updated and here's what `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'` gives me

```
/home/spike/go/bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28\.0\.3
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.1/bin
/home/spike/go/bin
/usr/local/go/bin
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28\.0\.3
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.1/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.6.1/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public
/usr/local/go/bin
/opt/X11/bin
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/tools
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
/Users/spike/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3
/usr/local/go/bin
/home/spike/go/bin
```

So the `$PATH` variable points to the right directory for the binary but when I give the command `assetfinder`, I get an error saying `-bash: assetfinder: command not found`

My mac currently runs Big Sur and my login shell is `/bin/bash` (and not `/bin/zsh`)

Can anyone please tell me the right way to go about adding this to `$PATH` so that autocomplete works properly?

Comment: It looks like you added `/home/spike/go/bin` instead of `/Users/spike/go/bin`. Also, the escapes in `28\.0\.3` will prevent it from working, and your adds are getting run multiple times (not really a problem, but not as clean as it could be).

Comment: ‍♂️

That was indeed the problem. If you can add it to the answer, I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: I don't think @GordonDavisson will get a notification unless you mention them.

Comment: You have your path being set in some file that's being executed every time you start a subshell, that's why your path is repeating like that.