# Mac Terminal PATH settings

Tags: macos, path, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset your PATH variable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11745/reset-your-path-variable)

Everytime I open Terminal I need to set the PATH using:

PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Otherwise commands like 'ls' do not work. This is a pain. How do you fix the PATH so that each time you open the Terminal you don't need to set the PATH?

Comment: If you need to do this every time, something is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by editing the `.profile` file in your home directory - just add your PATH command into there and it will be executed each time you open a Terminal window.

You can read about some other ways to do this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603785/environment-variables-in-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

One good way is to set your environment variables in `/etc/launchd.conf`, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x/588442#588442). Putting them in launchd.conf makes them accessible in the terminal as well as in any code you may write which uses the environment settings.