# How to reset $PATH?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, command-line

I was trying to add something to $PATH and it went totally wrong.  I now can't run any commands such as `ls`.  I've looked at this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11745/reset-your-path-variable)  and used the following lines:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

These lines fix the problem temorarily; however, when I restart terminal it seems to forget these changes.

How do I permanently reset my $PATH?

I'm running the most recent version of Mountain Lion.

Comment: Fixed it: `/bin/rm ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Good question. You could always put your fix in an answer.

Comment: Also asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/538400/4714)

Comment: Realizing you already fixed your problem, users with a similar issue might also find help at `/etc/paths`

Answer (score 23):

The suggested answer of removing `.bash_profile` is not a good idea in general. There are other things that can be set in that file besides `PATH` definitions.

If you want to undo the effects of your experimentation, just remove or comment out that `PATH` line with a `#`.

You don't want to edit the `PATH` from scratch, but append to it, as you did with your second line. The preferred method of adding something to your path would be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

**EDIT**
Since your `PATH` is messed up, you don't have access to the usual commands to make these changes. As a temporary fix, you can define a new minimal path *in a Terminal window* (not in your `.bash_profile`) by typing:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
```

This will temporarily give you access to `nano ls mv vi cat` and `rm` -- the basic tools to check and edit your `.bash_profile` and fix your problem...

Repeat, do not put this `PATH` definition anywhere except for the duration of the session while you make your fixes.

Comment: For newer OS, your settings will be in `.zshrc` instead. Check which shell using `echo $SHELL`

Comment: There should be no need to explicitly `export` the variable; this particular variable will already be `export`ed by your shell, so there is no need to do it again.

Answer (score 15):

I recommend:

```
source /etc/profile
```

This is what Mac uses to set the initial path, and it will put everything back in place excepting the items that you are adding for your user.

I do a decent amount of path modification in my ~/.bash_profile, and I've placed this at the top of the file because I was having issues with reloading my profile while I'm working after I tweak an alias in there or something, and it was adding duplicate references to my path. Instead of checking to see if it's already added, I just reset my path to the scratch version and re-append the items I want.

UPDATE: When switching to `zsh`, I changed my `.bash_profile` to `.zshrc` and then changed my reload profile alias to source the `/etc/zprofile`, which resets the path to scratch as described earlier for bash. Here's the alias I have defined so that I can quickly reload my profile:

```
alias reloadprofile='source /etc/zprofile && source ~/.zshrc'
```

I believe you can accomplish the same thing by calling `exec zsh`, which replaces the current instance with a new one and reloads the `.zshrc` file, but I haven't experimented enough with it to be completely sure.

Comment: I had to modify this a little to get it to work for me. I created two aliases– `alias bashr='. ~/.zshrc'` and `alias loadDefaultPath='. /etc/zprofile'`. Then in **.zshrc** I execute `export PATH=""`, `loadDefaultPath`, and `export PATH="${PATH}"`. For clarification `.` is the same as `source` in the aliases I have defined above.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the your bash profile to restore the default `$PATH`. Enter the following command into **Terminal.app**:

```
/bin/rm ~/.bash_profile
```

The change will take place with the next shell or terminal session.

Comment: Answering, based on original questioner's comments, to remove the question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep other content of your profile, a simple `/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile ~/bash_profile` might be better

Comment: This is the simplest answer I have found in the entire SE websites. Thanks!

Comment: Most effective answer for sure

Comment: Unfortunately, this is hopelessly and dangerously wrong in the general case. If you _only_ set your `PATH` in `.bash_profile`, this is an acceptable solution; but the file has many other uses, and if you use the terminal for any amount of time, you will probably have added other things there which you will not want to lose.

Answer (score 3):

OSX's default `$PATH` is generated from the contents of the `/etc/paths` file, it's fairly straight-forward to modify.

Comment: Modifying `/etc/paths` carries the risk of changes getting overwritten by the next OS X update, also this doesn't work for user-specific paths like `~/bin`.

Comment: That's true, though I usually handle those in my .rc's later. I also haven't had my `/etc/paths` reset yet by an update (several years now since I started using `brew`).

Comment: Currently hacking on a [boxen provisioning](https://boxen.github.com) that I hope will make me impervious to future overwriting updates.

Comment: On a single-user system the distinction is somewhat unimportant; but the files in `/etc` define system-wide defaults, unlike the files in your personal home directory.

Answer (score -1):

These methods are great! If you have this problem with zsh, remove `~/.zshrc` This will get rid of your zsh settings though.

Comment: You would rather want to keep a copy `/bin/mv ~/.bash_profile{,.bck}`

Comment: Better to just edit your settings. This is like suggesting that to delete a file you could just reformat your hard drive.